# Simplify the expression and leave answer in terms of $\sin x$ and/or $\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

$1-\sin^2 x = \cos^2 x$. However, $1-\sin^2 x$ can also be factored using the difference of two squares. I am stuck on whether $1- \sin^2 x$ should turn into $\cos^2 x$ **or** be factored by using the difference of two squares approach.

---

My work:

> \begin{align*}
> \cot^2x-\cos^2x&= \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2x}-\frac{\cos^2 x}{1\cdot \sin^2 x}\cdot \sin^2 x\\
> &=\frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}\\
> &=\cos^2x\frac{(1-\sin^2x)}{\sin^2x}\\
> &=\boxed{\frac{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{(\sin x)(\sin x)}}
> \end{align*}

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAU79.jpg)

Comment: We strongly encourage that you learn to format your questions and work in progress.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The editing is correct. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand what the question was exactly

Comment: Question asks to keep ans in cos,sin so second last step would do

Comment: What is the point to factorize $1-\sin^{2} x$, etc?  The answer is $\displaystyle \frac{\cos^{4} x}{\sin^{2} x}$ immediately after the second last line.

Comment: @NgChungTak Yeah I did not realize there are many ways alternative ways of solving this problem. The most concise one as you and probablyme have mentioned is the one I am going to go with. Also I did not realize that the answer could be squared because when the directions said to leave the answer in terms of sin or cos of x I thought that meant no squaring was allowed. But I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying there is a *right* answer? Because usually simplification comes down to personal preference.

Aside from the fact that you forgot the $\cos^2 x$ in the last line, it seems
$$\frac{(\cos^2x)(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{(\sin x)(\sin x)}$$ is fine. Possible acceptable alternatives are

1. $$\frac{(\cos^2x)(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{\sin^2 x}$$
2. $$\frac{\cos^2 x (1-\sin^2 x)}{\sin^2 x}$$
3. and $$\frac{\cos^4 x}{\sin^2 x}$$

<strike>As you can see there really isn't/shouldn't be a right answer. Although, number 3 is the most brief.</strike>
I change my mind; they probably want number 3.

Answer (score 0):

Both your original picture scan and the working above have lost the $\cos^2(x)$ factor on the RHS in the last step. The last line should read
something like:
$$=(\cos^2x)\frac{(1+\sin x)(1-\sin x)}{(\sin x)(\sin x)}$$